# Почему иногда не подхватывается SSL сертификат при обращении к сайту?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, letsencrypt

Иногда при обращении к сайту (не удалось выявить закономерность, когда именно) Chrome пишет, что сайт не защищен. При этом если **просто обновить** страницу, то все начинает работать нормально.

[image: SSL Error]

На хостинге Ubuntu, на нем стоит Apache и прикручены сертификаты Let's Encrypt через Certbot, который их автоматически перезапрашивает.

Я бы понял, если бы это происходило в день перевыпуска, но сегодня поймал этот баг, хотя сертификат выпущен давно и действителен до сентября.

Конфиги сервера:

```
<VirtualHost site.ru:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    ServerName site.ru
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}=site.ru
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

SSL:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost site.ru:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@site.ru
        ServerName site.ru
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

В `letsencrypt.log` все хорошо:

```
...
2022-07-20 07:12:54,816:DEBUG:certbot.renewal:no renewal failures
```

В `error.log` Apache тоже ничего связанного с этой проблемой

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с этим или хотя бы подскажите куда копать и какие логи/конфиги смотреть?

Comment: Может, проблема в вашем компьютере? Происходит ли это на других компьютерах/браузерах?

Comment: @andreymal ни с одним другим сайтом такой проблемы с этого же пк нет. На других устройствах/браузерах замечено не было, но это не очень часто происходит (может раз в неделю или реже) и искусственно не воспроизводится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема исчезла после выполнения глобального обновления сервера через

```bash
apt upgrade
```

Примечательно, что версия ssl как раз не поменялась и какой именно пакет был причиной я так и не понял. Но, тем не менее, это помогло.